# If a user has created an account on my iOS app using Google, how should I handle their effort to also create an email account?

Tags: ios, login, error-message, google, authentication

Imagine a user logged into my iOS app using their Google account. Months later, they are trying to create an account using their email address (the same one connected to their previous Google social login). Should I

a) serve them an error message reading "This email is tied to a Google-authenticated account already in our system."

Or

b) simply let them create the account again - and figure out how to merge the 2 accounts together seamlessly?

If it's b), can you explain the technical hurdles I'll run into by merging the two accounts? I'm preparing my specs and want to communicate my needs to the engineers as succinctly as possible. Thanks!

Comment: It should be (a). Personally, I think you should always guide users to create account on your website rather than using 3rd party logins. Because using 3rd party logins often confuse users on which service they have used to login the last time. So the rule of thumb for me is, use the 3rd party login information to create an account on your own website, in other words make the registration as simple as you can by using 3rd party login APIs.

Comment: It depends on specifics. Is the email address the username? If so, that needs to be unique. So they couldn't have two accounts with the same username in the first place.

Comment: As for b) that's a question entirely dependent on your code base. We can't answer that.

Comment: @Ades, are you saying "use Google to authenticate their account", but still ask them to create their own account? I'm confused by your suggestion. I'm imagining you mean: Google authenticates their account, but they additionally create their own username and password for my product. please clarify.

Comment: @DA01, the code base isn't built yet - so, yes, please speculate on the best practices that should be designed into the code architecture. Re: the username - email is the primary account identifier. Regardless, my focus is how to handle the situation of them attempting to create a custom login after they've already associated their account to Google. The chances of them ending up w/ 2 accounts is possible, if, for example, their Google account is not the same email address as their custom login. If so, I hope they use the same name so i can alert them as to the overlap & merge their accounts.

Comment: @user654227 they can't as then they'd have two accounts with the same email. So that's going to be an error situation. If their Google account is not the same as their custom login, then there's no conflict. As far as you are concerned, that's two different users.

Comment: I mean use Facebook, Google etc for only registration purposes and not login. Login should be via your own website.

Comment: @DA01, we're on the same page about it being an error situation. The question is how to best handle that error. I've found Facebook's docs to have great suggestions - in the case of social login > same email address, let them login, giving the illusion they've created a custom account and add that password to their profile. Later, they can simply login via either method (social or custom). It might be befuddling to see their FB picture show up when they thought they'd just logged in via custom. My solution for that is to expose the fact they've connected to FB or Google in the Account screens.

Comment: I guess I'm confused. How can they log in with an existing email that's already attached to a different login? Or is Facebook suggestion people be allowed to create multiple logins with the same email, but all accounts are merged into one? I think you are on the right track, though. If they try and make an account with their email that's already in use, simply say "this account is already in use via "google/facebook"...

Comment: @Ades - just to clarify, let's focus on iOS, not website, please. If one 'registers' using Facebook or Google, you have their email address. Why not use it to let them login? The only reason i'm including FB and Google is to reduce the sign up friction - I'm not incorporating social features such as post to FB or Google Plus.

Comment: @DA01, yeah, it's kind of mind numbing - all these different use cases. I believe Facebook is saying "yeah, you can login with an email that's connected to an account - if that account is an FB account - and you are attempting to create a custom account - because we recognize the fact that the product you are using  (see their Xbox/Netflix example) doesn't always accept the FB login - or you've simply forgotten that you previously logged in w/ FB. It's still you - the user with the name@email.com. Let's give you some flexibility - we'll simply append that custom password to u -name@email.com.

Comment: I would go for A simply for security reasons

Comment: @JonasDralle I'm imagining the security threat. A) I have stolen a phone, I launch the user's app, it happens to be logged out (pretty unlikely), I attempt to login using what I think is the user's preferred email address, i get an error message saying "already tied to a Google account", my plan is foiled. B) I don't get an error message, my plan isn't foiled, I'm logged in! What can I steal? ... Then again, with A the thief will simply hit the back button and login using Google - probably not having to enter the password again. So 1 extra tap to get in. UX of B is worth the risk yeah?

Comment: B is making the whole process more complex because you are able to create multiple accounts on an single adress and thus you need to remember whixj way of logging in you used. Plus as a thief when you only have access to Google you could simply click on "Forgot my Password" and because it's registered to the google mail you get the email which you can use to get into the accoubt even wothout knowing the password for the other logon method. None of them is more secure against thiefs but B is still more complex as far as I experience it

Answer (score 2):

c) Just log them into their existing account with no error message.  *(I just tried it and confirmed this is what StackExchange does.)*  Serving an error message and making the user navigate to the login page and retype their credentials is a poor experience.  Once the user is logged in, it will be clear that they didn't need to sign up as they already had an account.  You should be ensuring that accessing your app is as quick and easy as possible, removing any possible barriers to entry.

Comment: Did you try from iOS? I've tried several times over the last 2 days on iOS8. First I turned off my open ID on the StackExchane website profile and left only my Google as one of my account log ins. Then i tried creating a custom(Stack Exchange) account in iOS. The error message was: Error - This email address is already in use. Then i tried logging in via the custom account (same email as my Google) and received the: Error - Bad Password. This is exactly the user experience I'm attempting to avoid. That's why I'm considering solution a) above.

Comment: I apologize, I only tried it in a desktop browser.  However, I still think this is the best solution.